# variadic functions with different types of arguments in c

Tags: c, function, variadic, variadic-functions

I was wondering if it's possible in C to create a variadic function that takes different types of arguments. i.e.

```
void fillDatabase(char* name, int age){
  writeToDatabase(name, age);
}

int main(){
  fillDatabase("Paul", 19);
  fillDatabase("Herbert");
}
```

Here I am trying to fill up a database with names and ages. But it's also possible to fill it up with only a name and no age. So I am wondering if I could use the same function for that or if I have to write two different ones?

[Online](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) I could only find examples for variadic functions with the same type of arguments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're mixing up the concepts of variadic functions and function overloading.

Comment: I added a link of what I found online

Comment: `printf` is a variadic function that can take different types of arguments... Note that you would need to provide some means of explicitly providing the argument types (which `printf`-like functions do via the format string).

Comment: so hold on, what does that mean in regards to my example?

Comment: The variadic function has to know the argument types, in `printf` etc this is done with the format specifiers.

Comment: It means that you should look at `printf` as an example. (BTW, the hoops that you have to jump through for variadic functions usually makes them not worth it.)

Comment: You need to be able to tell which type each argument has, and how many arguments there are.

Comment: It could be done with each argument a `struct` or `union` specifying the data type and value, with a sentinel to end the sequence.

Comment: Just *write two functions*. Writing a variadic function, using a `struct`, `union` or any other trick just asks for trouble. Seriously.

Comment: Guys, if somebody asks you to help him shoot himself in the foot, you don't give him a gun... at the very least not without asking for a good reason...

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll just use two functions

Comment: Just FYI, variadic functions should generally only be used when you *can't* know the number of variables at compile time or the number of variables is orthogonal.  Otherwise, the benefits are... debatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C99, variadic functions use [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) operations (generally implemented as macros expanding to *compiler-specific* magical stuff, e.g. GCC builtins). The first arguments should have some fixed known type, and generally determinates how the other arguments are fetched; in several today's ABIs, variadic function argument passing don't use registers so is less efficient than fixed arity function calls.

In your case, **you'll better have several functions**. For inspiration sqlite has [several open functions](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

Notice that POSIX defines some function with one *last* optional argument, in particular [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). This is probably implemented as having a function whose *last* argument can be not supplied.

You could read the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification and the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) specific to your implementation.

BTW, lack of function overloading (like in C++) can be understood as an advantage of C (the function name -which is the only thing the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) care about, at least on Linux & Unix- determines its signature). Hence C++ practically needs [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Read also about [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) and [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html)

Comment: Traditionally, no prototype for `open()` was supplied so programmers could call it with two or three arguments as needed. Nowadays, `open()` is declared as `int open(const char*, int, ...);` and uses variable arguments.

Comment: In practice, not really.

Comment: So [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is wrong in this regard?

Comment: No, I thought that *implementations* of `open` don't use `va_start`, but in musl-libc [open.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/fcntl/open.c) `va_start` is used. So I was wrong. IIRC, some old versions of Glibc didn't do that (but I might be wrong too)

Comment: As I said, old implementations of `open()` just didn't supply a prototype and defined `open()` with a K&R-style definition and three arguments. The argument count mismatch is undefined behaviour, but works just fine on typical Unices as long as you never touch arguments that weren't supplied.

Answer (score 2):

Check the man page for va_list, va_start, etc.

You declare your function prototype using the ... sequence to denote variable args:

```
void myfunction(FILE *, *fmt, ...);
```

For example, we declatre a struct of type va_list (assuming you included stdarg):

```
struct va_list l;
```

Initialise the list using the parameter BEFORE the ... - se we'd pass the *fmt pointer to va_start:

```
va_start(l, fmt);
```

Now, we can call va_arg to get a value...if we're processing a format string we might have a loop something like this:

```
while (*fmt) {
    /* Look for % format specifier... */
    if (*fmt == '%') {
        /* Following character can be c for char, i for int or f for float. */
        // Opps - advance to char following opening %...
        fmt++;

        if (*fmt == 'c')
            fprintf(stream, "%c", (char) va_arg(l, int));
        else if (*fmt == 'i')
            fprintf(stream, "%i", (int) va_arg(l, int));
        else if (*fmt == 'f')
            fprintf(stream, "%f", (float) va_arg(l, double));
        ... and so on...
```

You're relying on the character following the % to tell you what data type to expect in the corresponding parameter. Suggest you read the man pages for va_list.

Comment: So how would you apply all this knowledge for the particular problem?

Comment: Well...I don't really know the ins and outs of the particular problem I'm not the OP. Let the OP decide if my answer is adequate for his/her purposes, if it is then great...if not then sorry, keep looking. I don't really know what you want or expect me to tell you...